# Azure Storage Client v4.1 - a value of the non-primitive type was expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-table-storage

I've recently upgraded my ASP.NET project (MVC5) to target Azure SDK 2.3 with Storage Library 4.1 and am encountering a strange error when I try to save anything to Table Storage.

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
>
> Additional information: A primitive value was specified; however, a value of the non-primitive type '' was expected.

My models go into table storage via repositories that use a `TableServiceContext` to add, update, delete, save.

I follow this pattern for my models:

```
[System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceKey(new string[] { "PartitionKey", "RowKey" })]
public class PersistedAlert : Alert, ITableEntity
{
    public string PartitionKey
    {
        get { return this.StudentId; }
        set { this.StudentId = value; }
    }

    public string RowKey
    {
        get { return this.Id; }
        set { this.Id = value; }
    }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public new int Type { get; set; } //hides Enum type in Alert base class
}
```

During the upgrade I needed to swap out all of my references to

> System.Data.Services.*

for

> Microsoft.Data.Services.*

...in addition to the OData libraries.

Has something changed internally that makes my pattern no longer valid?

Comment: I'm having the same error, with an empty expected type, using Web API 2 and OData V4... there's absolutely no help on this error what so ever. This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

Since there's nothing (yet) on this error on the net, and this is pretty much the only place it's discussed, I'll add a solution even though my context is different than yours. The error is exactly the same so I guess it originates from the same place.

For me, it was a inherited primary key that caused the problem. The primary key of the serialized entity has to be natural and not overriden. If Class has an ID property, DerivedClass will also have to declare the ID property as "new", or the ID property has to be moved from Class to DerivedClass.

Here's more detail: http://jerther.blogspot.ca/2014/12/aspnet-odata-v4-primitive-value-was.html

I do believe this is a bug and not a limitation as the inherited key works very well with Entity Framework and Fluent API.

I hope this helps and saves some hair pulling.

Comment: This happened to me when I used the fluent API to map a field to the same name as another field. From both our situations I believe this error is caused by two fields mapped with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to upgrade all of the repository code to move away from the WCF based `TableServiceContext` which is deprecated and instead make calls via `CloudTable`. I can only assume something internally changed to one of the above mentioned libraries that resulted in the problem I was seeing.

In addition to changing the repository code, I also needed to update my entities to inherit from the Azure `ITableEntity` (I had my own flavour previously), like this:

```
public class PersistedAlert : Alert, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.ITableEntity
{
        public string PartitionKey
        {
            get { return this.StudentId; }
            set { this.StudentId = value; }
        }

        public string RowKey
        {
            get { return this.Id; }
            set { this.Id = value; }
        }

        public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }

        public string ETag { get; set; }

        public void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty> properties, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity.ReadUserObject(this, properties, operationContext);
        }

        public IDictionary<string, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty> WriteEntity(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            return Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity.WriteUserObject(this, operationContext);
        }
}
```